# Struggling with self-learning economics through textbook readings

Tags: microeconomics

I am trying to self-learn introductory microeconomics by following a textbook, Microeconomics by Christopher T.S. Ragan. I am not currently enrolled in a course, I am just self-learning in preparation for a future introductory course in microeconomics. However, I find myself constantly getting stuck trying to understand explanations in the textbook and I am making minimal progress. To be honest, I have never learned a subject by simply reading a textbook (more of a class/videos person) and I am wondering if this strategy is inefficient.

Should I instead use the textbook as a reference material for practice problems and rely on videos/Khan academy to introduce myself to the concepts? Does relying on video/lectures make me a weaker student or disadvantage me once I take an intermediate economics class? I am not an economics major and I only require a handful of economics courses to complete my major. I am finding the process of self-learning to be really difficult and I would appreciate any advice/tips to be more efficient. Thank you.

Comment: Could be a bad textbook but probably you just need to adopt another reading strategy. Something like: Read chapter, test your self on main concepts, can you explain them, read chapter again, make exercises, can you solve them. It is always good to look at alternative resources, but it is also good to have a primary source. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

These are some good introductory resources that I have found helpful:

https://mru.org/principles-economics-microeconomics
https://app.senecalearning.com/dashboard/courses/add?text=economics

I really encourage you to attempt the questions as it will help you understand and apply the theories

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the open course in Microeconomics offered by MIT:

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/economics/14-01sc-principles-of-microeconomics-fall-2011/index.htm

There is an open source alternative to the suggested text book. You could look for other similar offerings and sample the materials offered to find a course that might work best for you.